# Install GDAL locally in a server without sudo permissions

Tags: gdal, server

I would like to install the last version of GDAL on my user space of a sever (ubuntu framework). I do not have permissions to use 'sudo' command because I have not 'root' permissions.

What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Are all tools present to build it from source?

Comment: I'm not sure. You should install also osgeo, I guess..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since i still can not create comment, i'll write this in answer section.

duplicate post: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/689065/how-could-i-install-gdal-without-root

Refer to the following link for installation instructions: 
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix

Comment: Yes, I did it. But then if i try to check if it is installed, I have this message:

Comment: The program 'gdalinfo' is currently not installed. To run 'gdalinfo' please ask your administrator to install the package 'gdal-bin'. And I tried to install 'gdal-bin' by using: 'apt-get install gdal-bin'...but I don't have permissions

Comment: don't forget to add path to the gdal binaries.

Comment: refer to this post on how to set your shell's PATH environment variable http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere

Comment: Changing the environmental variable should be enough? I unzipped gdal-2.1.0.tar.gz in my user folder in the server. How do I find the gdal-binaries

Comment: look for bin directory inside the source folder, or you can use --prefix to specify tatget install folder. refer to this for more details: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix

Comment: It works! Can you edit your answer with the last link you suggested me, as perfectly answer my question. Thank you

Comment: answer updated,